# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar. while passing large date differance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[performance]
(@startdate nvarchar(100), @enddate nvarchar(100)
as begin
    declare @date1 nvarchar(100) = convert(varchar, @startdate+' 00:00:00.000', 120)

    declare @date2 nvarchar(100) = convert(varchar, @enddate+' 23:59:59.000', 120)

    set NOCOUNT on;
    select l.LocName,v.Vtype, SUM(DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)) as TotalDiff,
    [dbo].[testfunction](
CONVERT(decimal(10,1), 
AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), DATEDIFF(SS,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ) )))  as Average
    from Transaction_tbl t
    left join VType_tbl v
        on t.vtid=v.vtid
    left join Location_tbl l
        on t.Locid=l.Locid
    where t.Locid in
        (select t1.Locid from Transaction_tbl t1)
    and dtime between '' + @date1 +'' and ''+ @date2 +''
    and Status =5
    group by v.Vtype,l.LocName,l.Locid order by l.Locid
end
```

My function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[testfunction] (@dec NUMERIC(18, 2)) RETURNS Varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN  DECLARE @hour integer,  @Mns integer,   
@second decimal(18,3)DECLARE @Average  Varchar(50)  
select @hour=CONVERT(int,@dec/60/60) 
SELECT @Mns = convert(int, (@dec / 60) - (@hour * 60 ));
select @second=@dec % 60; 

SELECT @Average = convert(varchar(9), convert(int, @hour)) + ':' +  right('00' + convert(varchar(8), convert(decimal(18,2), @Mns)), 2) + ':' +
right('00' + CONVERT(decimal(10,0), convert(varchar(10), @second)), 6)
RETURN @Average end
```

if i pass start date:2013-06-01 and end date:2013-08-01 then getting proper out put if i pass start date:2010-06-01 and end date:2013-08-01 (bigger date difference) then getting error: what is wrong with my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to also post the exact error you get in the question.

However, here's my guess about what may be happening: I think the error is due to the expression `SUM(DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))`, more specifically it's possible that the total value exceeds the signed int max value (`2147483647`).

It is possible because:

- the DateDiff function returns a signed integer according to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)
- the difference in minutes for a period of 3 years is approximately 1.5M: (`select datediff(mi, '2010-01-01', '2013-01-01')` --> `1578240`). If you sum up about 2000 such records, it's possible that you exceed the signed int range.

So, if your error is

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

consider converting the minute difference to a data type with a wider range (for example, `bigint` or `numberic(18, 2)` as you did with a few rows below).

Concretely, you'll need to replace

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))
```

with

```
SUM(convert(numeric(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)))
```

Comment: sir i have one more doubt..can i ask?